# pendingintent not working sometimes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a home screen widget which has text views. When I click on the text view my Main activity opens. I have set a PendingIntent on the text views.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw1, pendingIntent);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw2, pendingIntent);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw3, pendingIntent);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);

    updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

This code works fine. But sometimes when i click on the text view nothing happens. The widget seems to get freezed. I have to manually open the main activity from my main application then the PendingIntent again works fine and the text view becomes clickable.

I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting too many elements into one Intent, have you ever tried to group them together with a layout, and set Intent on that layout instead?

Plus, it's recommended to add flags to your Intent, I usually use

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

and

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

And also set in the pending Intent

```
setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.contentw3,0, pendingIntent, 
                        PendingItent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```